# Custom component in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to make a custom component in my JavaFX-App that I can re-use, but it doesn't seem to be recognized as a component. When I try to open an fxml-file in Scene Builder, it says that the Class could't be found. I try to import it in the fxml file using the full namespace of the class, I can't see why it doesn't work.

```
<?import com$mynamespace$myapp$views$ShopOrderDetailView
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
```

This is the class of my custom component:

```
    public class ShopOrderDetailView extends VBox {


    public ShopOrderDetailView() {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                "order-detail-view.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

}
```

In the parent fxml file this line causes the SceneBuilder to cash:

```
<?import com.mynamespace.myapp.views.ShopOrderDetailView?>
```

The namespace is correct and I can navigate to the class using strg+click.

When I try to add the component inside a controller.java file, I also get an exception at the instantiation:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
```